# Is this the correct logging behaviour in Camel Spring DSL?

Tags: apache-camel, dsl

I watched this interesting logging behaviour using Spring DSL:

```
<log message=”${exchange}”/> gives the exchange id
<log message=”${header}”/> gives the headers
<log message=”${body}”/> gives the body
```

And, since it was a lot of fun, let us do it again:

```
<log message=”${exchange}”/> gives the exchange id
<log message=”${header}”/> gives the headers
<log message=”${body}”/> gives nothing
```

The body has been overwritten with an empty string be the first log statement. Is this expected behaviour? I guess not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its expected behaviour. See this FAQ about why you can get empty body: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html